# How to expand the \caption-command to pre-insert the affiliated source of figure/table?

Tags: captions, environments, source

In scientific works it is quite common to specify the source for every statement. This is also necessary for tables or images of course.

Usually I'm always using the `\caption`-command for adding some description to tables and figures. Unfortunately, I have to put in the source of that table/figure manually by myself all the time.

**In the past, I tricked it like that (what is really annoying time by time):**

```
\caption[Caption]{Caption\newline\footnotesize{Source: Own representation}}
```

Here is some MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figs/test1.png}
        \caption[Caption for lof]{Caption for figure\newline\footnotesize{Source: Own representation}}
    \end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

---

**Now I had an idea:**

What if one could insert an additional `{}`-variable to the `\caption`-command to get a separate field for adding the source?

---

Right now, it looks like that (standard-command):

```
\caption[Caption for list of figures]{Caption for figure itself}
```

What if we could expand that `\caption`-command to get something like that:

```
\caption[Caption for list of figures]{Caption for figure itself}{Source}
```

---

The dreamlike solution would be to auto-fill the text `Source: Own representation` if one doesn't fill in some other text into that field. That could be handled with some `if/else`-commands like that:

```
If the field is empty: Insert "Source: Own representation"

If the field is NOT empty: Insert "Source: {Inserted text}"
```

---

**Do you have any idea how one could get that?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest not to change the syntax of `\caption`, but defining a `\Caption` command with the help of `xparse`. The syntax is

```
\Caption[<caption for lof>]{Caption}[<optional source>]
```

The first optional argument has the usual meaning; the trailing optional argument specifies the source; if empty, “Own representation” is used.

Here are some examples of usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Caption}{
  O{#2}                 % optional (default = value of mandatory argument)
  m                     % mandatory
  O{Own representation} % optional (default = given text)
}{%
  \caption[#1]{#2\newline\footnotesize Source: #3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}

\Caption
  [Caption for lof]
  {Caption for figure}[Some author]
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}

\Caption
  {Caption for figure}[Some author]
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}

\Caption{Caption for figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right! Furthermore, my system missed the first [] before the {}. After inserting that, everything worked fine! :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another approach: define a variant of `\includegraphics` to add a second optional argument which incorporates the source, thanks to the `copyrightbox` package  and `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\myincludegraphics{o O{Source: Own representation} m }{%
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{#3}}{#2}}%
{\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \myincludegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth][Yuri Norstein]{loupnorstein2}
        \caption[Caption for lof]{Tale of tales (1979)}
    \end{figure}%

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \myincludegraphics{Hedgehog-in-the-Fog}
        \caption[Caption for lof]{Hedgehog in the fog (1975)}
    \end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great solution, it's looking perfect! Unfortunately, one can not use that for tables... There is no option to get something like that with the \caption-command?

Comment: I don't see how it could be done. But you can use  `\copyrightbox` with tables. The only problem is you do not have the equivalent of `\includegraphics` for tables. That said, you can obtain a very similar result with `threepartable` and its `tablenotes`. The only superiority of `copyrightbox` is you can place the affiliated source on any side of the table/figure.